# how do i make these edges parallel?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

hei guys, i am trying to figur out how to make these two sides parallel to each other...
you can see in the picture which side i want to be parallel to the opposite side.

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Knife tool and make it stick to this vertex so that it extend the edge:

[image]

Another solution, a bit more tedious, first enable the *Auto Merge* option:

[image]

Then create a loopcut:

[image]

Slide it with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>, or <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> right away so that it stay parallel to the next edge:

[image]

Move it until it sticks to the next edge, the vertices will merge thanks to the *Auto Merge* option:

[image]

Remove the unwanted vertices:

[image]

Or you could select the edge, duplicate, separate the duplication to make it a new object, and use it as cutting object with the *Knife Project* tool (snap it to the vertex). Or enable *Auto Merge*, duplicate the edge, move it, snap, extend with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>, select all, press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, it has cut the edge into the face:

[image]

Comment: oh ok nice, thats great to know too! thanks a lot for your solution :)

Comment: @minkche For the _Edge Slide_ method it is important to know that it only works because the two edges on the right are in a 90° angle to each other. If they were not, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I'm not sure what your mean, here the edges are not 90°: https://zupimages.net/up/22/36/la4a.gif

Comment: @moonboots No, they are not 90° - but the angle is not different enough from 90° to see the effect. If the angle differs more, it becomes more obvious (I also aligned the shape with the grid so you can see it even better): [edges not parallel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KxzOOYXvkVGn6SBY8XLI238W7praT6Lv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann ok my bad then  ;)

Answer (score 1):

so this is my solution for those who may look for the same solution.

delete mesh, until it is back to the parallel part
[image: delete mesh, until it is back to the parallel part]
extrude with edge snap on
[image: extrude with edge snap on]

select vertices that should align with bottom piece and egde slide with 2xG and snap to edge
[image: select vertices that should align with bottom piece and egde slide with 2xG and snap to edge]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried to select those 2 edges, go to top-down view, snap to increment, zoomed in and move the edge to be in parallel with the other side?

Comment: i tried just now, but it is just guessing in the end, isnt it?

Comment: Guessing as in, you are unsure if its precise enough? or in relation to my answer?

It looks like you are trying to build something very complex and I am probably underestimating your skills but have you tried simply extruding and moving the 2 faces for the edges to align with each other?

I do not work on extremely precise assets, and not an expert, so I may not be much help.

Comment: i just found a solution, after reading your comment :D
i deleted the part which was not parallel and extruded with edge snap to snap one side to the edge of the bottom picece of the construct. Then i selected te other vertices and snapped them to the edge of the bottom piece with 2xG(edge slide). 

oh and sorry, i meant the guessing as in being technical unprecise, not your answer itself.

Comment: I am glad your problem is solved.

Comment: thank you for your reply dude :)